# Can I show the responses to all the requests at once in the Firefox Network Monitor?

Tags: firefox-developer-tools

I am trying to understand a website's API by reading the responses to the XHR requests in the Firefox Console or Network Monitor. In particular, I want to find which XHR request has a response containing specific text.

For each request, I can click on the request in the console to expand it, then go to the Response tab in the expanded section, then click Raw to show the JSON returned by the website. But this is slow to do for all the XHR requests.

Can I make Firefox display all of these responses at once, in a raw-text format that I can search? Alternatively, can I view and search all the responses at once in some other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for something similar to Burp Suite's Sitemap tool. Launch the auto-proxied chromium browser (or just the proxy and configure your browser to use it) and browse a site that makes calls to the API. It will record each exchange and organize them into a sort of directory tree based on request paths and origin.

See more info and source of the following sample screenshot here: https://portswigger.net/burp/documentation/desktop/tools/target/site-map/getting-started
[image: PortSwigger Site map GUI]

Note that the paid version is required in order to "Save" a constructed sitemap. The community edition is otherwise fine and supports global/scoped searches, and you can always manually record any useful info you may want until you've decided to exit and end the session.